# Glue Transform not finding argument passed to Glue Job

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-glue

Lambda function triggered by CSV dropped into S3 bucket. Lambda then calls a Glue Job.

Error occurs in "Transform-Custom Code" node in line 2:

```
def MyTransform (glueContext, dfc) -> DynamicFrameCollection:
    rules_file_path = glueContext.get_job_run().get_job_argument("--rules-file-path")
```

Error "AttributeError: 'GlueContext' object has no attribute 'get_job_run'".

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you pass the arguments to a Glue job via `start_job_run()`, you can retrieve the parameters in the Glue job with:

In the Lambda that calls the glue job:

```py
response = glue.start_job_run(JobName=glue_job_name, Arguments={"--rules-file-path": rules_file_path})
```

In the Glue Job Transform Code:

```py
import sys
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['rules-file-path'])
rules-file-path = args['rules-file-path']
```

Ref: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-get-resolved-options.html

Comment: Thanks! I tried your solution with both ['rules-file-path'] and ['--rules-file-path'] on the receiving end (glue job) and latest error is GlueArgumentError: the following arguments are required: ----rules-file-path. BTW I made sure in the advanced area of job details to put in both rules-file-path and --rules-file-path. Same in the lambda that calls this.